# C# Split Input after word not after space

Tags: c#, input

```
Console.Write(currentDirectory + ">");
string commandinput = Console.ReadLine();
string userinput = commandinput.ToLower();
char[] delim = new char[] { ' ' };
string[] splitted = userinput.Split(delim);

string userinput1 = splitted[0];
string userinput2 = splitted[1];
```

This is my current code.
It works but i have a Problem.
if the user writes "ping google.com" everything is finde and my pinger works.
But i also have a command "clear" that clears the console.
And if the user writes "clear" it gives an error:

**"index was outside the bounds of the array."**

Because there is nothing i wrote where it can split the input.
How can i change it, that it splits the input after the first word and not the space?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `"clear".Split(' ')` works well and returns a single row string array.

You should check the `splitted.Length` before trying to read your array:

```
string userinput1 = splitted[0];
string userinput2 = string.Empty;
if (splitted.Length > 1) {
    string userinput2 = splitted[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I accept it in 7 minutes :D

Answer (score 0):

You do something more like:

```
string userinput1 = splitted[0];
string userinput2 = splitted.Length > 1 ? splitted[1] : null;
```

But bear in mind if you try to use userinput2 later without first checking if it is null, then you'll get a NullReferenceException